# Javascript Select Option not updating

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown which when an option is selected it needs to populate an input value with the value of the option selected only its not working as in nothings changing, Could anybody see and explain why going of my code?

```
 <select id="corr_sel" onchange="updatecredoff();"> 
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
 </select>

<div id="cr_off"><?php echo $user_curr_coff;?></div>

function updatecredoff() {
    if(value == 1) {
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '1';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '1';
        }
    else if(value == 2) {
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '2';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '2';
        }
    else if(value == 3) {
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '3';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '3';
        }
    else if(value == 4) {
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '4';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '4';
        }
    else if(value == 5) {
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '5';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '5';
        }
    else if(value == 6) {
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '6';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '6';
        }
    else if(value == 7) {           
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '7';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '7';
        }
    else if(value == 8) {
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '8';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '8';
        }
    else if(value == 9) {
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '9';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '9';
        }
    else {
        document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '10';
        document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = '10';
    }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined `value` anywhere in your code (at least from what you've shown) before this:

```
if(value == 1) {
```

You could define `onchange="updatecredoff(this);` with `this` attached, and then in your function before your first conditional assign the value:

```
function updatecredoff(e) {
    value = e.value;
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/yXHD5/

Or you could just get the value by the ID like this:

```
value = document.getElementById("corr_sel").value;
```

If that is all the functionality you intend to do with the function, you could simplify it to just:

```
function updatecredoff(e) {
    document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = e.value;   
};
```

Comment: So would I say if(document.getElementById("corr_sel").value = '4';) { DO THIS } ?

Comment: @Liam exactly, but it'd be a lot more efficient to just assign it to a variable, and then check that variable with the conditions.

Comment: One last thing, how would i go about setting the selected value to the value in the cr_off div?

Comment: If you assigned it to a variable like this `value = document.getElementById("corr_sel").value;` then you can put it into that element with `document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = e.value;   `

Answer (score 1):

where did the var "Value" come from, you have not initialised it in the code.

You're code will work just fine like this.

```
 document.getElementById("cr_off").innerHTML = document.getElementById("corr_sel").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that `value` isn't defined, your function looks very redundant. Selecting an item from the `select` element changes its `selectedIndex` property, which you can  subsequently use to retrieve the value and write it to a text input field. E.g. like this:

```
function updatecredoff(el) {
    document.getElementById('cr_off').value = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
};
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gdwvd/) to play with